# Does the hitting time of +1/-1 of a Brownian motion posess a density?

Tags: pr.probability, brownian-motion, laplace-transform

The law of the hitting time of a 1-dimensional Brownian motion $W$ is well known, but I can't find any information on the density of the hitting time of $|W|$.

I define $T=\inf \{t>0,|W|(t)= 1\}$. One can find some useful informations about this random variables like its expectation 1, variance $\frac{2}{3}$ or Laplace transform $\mathbb{E}[e^{-xT}]=\frac{1}{\cosh(\sqrt{2x})}$ (see Revuz and Yor).

How can I know if $T$ has a density ? Can I inverse the Laplace transform easily (numerically could be enough) ? Any additional information on $T$ would be appreciated.

Comment: It will definitely follow from the formula for the Laplace transform. I would in fact instead look at the Fourier transform, which is smooth and exponentially decaying by this formula.

Comment: I would have prefered to find the Fourier transform, but a closed formula does not seem to exist. Have you got a reference for inversing the Laplace transform ?

Comment: The FT is the holomorphic continuation of the Laplace transform, just use the same formula.

Comment: Ok! Thank you.
Would you by chance know a way to derive a closed formula for the density ?

Comment: I think there probably isn't a closed form expression.  In Karatzas and Shreve, Exercise 8.11, you can find an infinite series expression of the density, which in particular shows that there is a density.  It converges super-exponentially.

Comment: Thank you. It will be useful for my work !
Do you know other references that study this variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The law of $T$ (and more generally the law of hitting times of Bessel processes) has been studied extensively in the literature, in particular by Marc Yor. In the survey

[PROBABILITY LAWS RELATED TO THE JACOBI THETA AND
RIEMANN ZETA FUNCTIONS, AND BROWNIAN EXCURSIONS](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2001-38-04/S0273-0979-01-00912-0/S0273-0979-01-00912-0.pdf)

$T$ is denoted by $C_1$ and several properties of the density are listed in the Table 1, page 443. 
Interestingly, the Mellin transform of $T$ is closely related to the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 1):

Computing the inverse Laplace transform can easily be done with the following python code

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576934/

or more accurateley (using the module mpmath)

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576938/

I've just computed the inverse.